# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label',how can I add label?

Tags: dataframe

I created a .csv which shows below, and when I try to use the label it told me"'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label'",the code is as follows
why my columns "cd,cs,cf" is not labels?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOCQ6.png)

I wish I input "aiya.label" it could turns out cd,cs,cf

Comment: As you can see in the output, there is no column called "label".

Comment: so how can I set the column name as label?

Comment: Is any of "cd, cs, cf" to be renamed as "label" or do you have a fourth column called "label" which you don't see here?

Comment: no I just input "cd,cs,cf"at the first line as column names in .csv,  I don't know how to let python see them as label

Comment: then I can do some work with code pd.value_counts(aiya.label)

Comment: sorry, i guess I misunderstand what the textbook say, thank you very much ,ahahaha